# How to position a table on Top of the text in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

let's say we have some text and we would like to drag the table on top of that text, how to

do this?? Because there is no such option in the table properties window

Comment: You want a table layered over-top of a section of text?

Comment: YES! I want a table layered over-top of a section of text

Comment: I don't think that's possible; but maybe someone else knows a way.  Perhaps make image out of your table and then layer that overtop of the text?

Comment: WTF?! scrsly?? funny workaround

Answer (score 5):

Put your table inside a Text Box.

Comment: Nice one! Works like a charm in Word 2007. You can even make the box background transparent. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why one would want it either. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would make an extra row on top of the table, then after entering the text use Eraser tool to remove borders. ( Eraser tool can be find under Table Tools -> Design -> Eraser )

Comment: True, I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement. I want to fill an entire page with a table (to make raffle tickets) so I need the distance from the top edge of the page to the top edge of the table the same at the bottom but Word won't allow it. There is an "End of Paragraph" marker at the bottom of the page that is taking up the last line. I can't move that marker NEXT TO the bottom of the table the way I could in WorPerfect.

Every time you go to Table Properties and select Table Wrapping as Around and select the Positioning button, set the Vertical Relative to: to Page and you move the table to center it vertically it spills into the second page.

Solution
Go to the second page and set the font size to 4 points. That centers the table and gets rid of the second page.